# Getting access to the layout metadata in Artifactory API

Tags: artifactory, package-repository

I am trying to query a JFrog Artifactory generic repository with artifacts that line up with the layout.

Each of the artifacts has a `groupId`, `artifactId`, `version`, and `type` shown in the UI that is being picked up from the file name and path. Plus, the ModuleID is showing the same information.

[image: module id]

[image]

I have tried hitting `api/search/artifact?name=<artifact>&repos=<repo-name>` but the result does not include any of this metadata.

```
            "repo": "generic-repo",
            "path": "/com/org/TestWebApp2/TestWebApp2-2.0.0.zip",
            "created": "2023-10-20T04:48:47.582Z",
            "createdBy": "admin",
            "lastModified": "2023-10-20T04:48:44.366Z",
            "modifiedBy": "admin",
            "lastUpdated": "2023-10-20T04:48:47.584Z",
            "downloadUri": "https://org.jfrog.io/artifactory/generic-repo/com/org/TestWebApp2/TestWebApp2-2.0.0.zip",
            "mimeType": "application/zip",
            "size": "679677",
            "checksums": {
                "sha1": "d6230604262fa191c6ace5d047562084ae863fbf",
                "md5": "87cf854c700475483251f622a8b615c9",
                "sha256": "945319dd0c3585cddcbd455d147d588072fc12513d822228d354af79fb214d8a"
            },
            "originalChecksums": {
                "sha1": "d6230604262fa191c6ace5d047562084ae863fbf",
                "md5": "87cf854c700475483251f622a8b615c9",
                "sha256": "945319dd0c3585cddcbd455d147d588072fc12513d822228d354af79fb214d8a"
            },
            "uri": "https://org.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/storage/generic-repo/com/org/TestWebApp2/TestWebApp2-2.0.0.zip"
        }
```

Preferably, I would like to be able to query using well-formed data, rather than having to parse the filename.

If my artifacts are adhering to the layout, how can I query the layout supplied data?